# Port Yii1 delete behavior to Yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii, delete-row

Default implementation of `delete` button in `CGridView` in Yii1 was done entirely on POST / AJAX and resulted in refresh of grid view after successful deletion of particular row.

In Yii2 this is a standard GET request, that redirects to given page after successful delete.

Is there an easy, core-based (without to much AJAX-JS digging) way of porting Yii1 behavior  to Yii2 -- to have AJAX-only delete and grid refresh after that delete?

Answer (score 0):

As per [*skworden*'s answer on Yii Framework Forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/63098-port-yii1-delete-behavior-to-yii2/page__view__findpost__p__278441), to implement (port) this behavior, one must use [PJAX](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html) as it is shown in "[How to use GridView with AJAX on Yii2](http://www.ramirezcobos.com/2014/04/26/how-to-use-gridview-with-ajax-on-yii2/)" article.